# 'S3' object has no attribute 'Bucket'

Tags: python, python-3.x, boto3

I'm receiving this error **'S3' object has no attribute 'Bucket'** any idea? below is my code

```
self.client = boto3.client(
        's3',
        aws_access_key_id= access_key,
        aws_secret_access_key= secret
    )
the_bucket = self.client.Bucket('my_bucket') # but I'm receiving an error here
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between resource,client and session..?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42809096/difference-between-resource-client-and-session)

Comment: You are confusing between boto3.s3.client vs boto3.s3.resource.   There is no such class for s3.client.Bucket , only s3.resource.Bucket is valid.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

There is more than one way to interact with Boto3.

The high-level one using `resource()` and classes like `S3.Bucket`.
And the low-level one using `boto3.client(...)`. You are kind of mixing these two.

If you look [here](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/clients.html) it will clarify the difference. In short...

**High-level example**

```
s3 = boto3.resource('s3') 
the_bucket = s3.Bucket('my_bucket')
```

**Low-level example**

```
self.client = boto3.client(...)
self.client.create_bucket(...)
```

Comment: Why distinguish the two? is there a benefit for using one over the other?

Comment: The documentation for boto3 is really confusing, the same thing happened to me to try to remove a file, I ended up mixing the methods. Here is the complete list of methods available for using the client mode: https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html?highlight=delete_object#client