# how to connect to region in boto3

Tags: python, boto3

How can one achieve the [boto](/questions/tagged/boto) command:

```
boto.ec2.connect_to_region()
```

using the boto3 suite?
It seems not to be at a glance in the [docs](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html)

I guess it's a simpler and more precise question than the extense answer you can find in the following [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42809096/difference-in-boto3-between-resource-client-and-session).

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 19, accepted):

boto3 wants you to specify the region by default. So, the solutions for you in Python is:

```
>>> import boto3
>>> boto_client = boto3.client('ec2', region_name='us-west-2')
```

You can also set up a default region. In order to do so:

```
>>> import boto3
>>> boto_client = boto3.setup_default_session(region_name='us-west-2')
>>> boto_client = boto3.client('ec2')
```