# DynamoDB with Boto3 - ResourceNotFoundException during table.scan()

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

I'm using DynamoDB to make a Room Booking Website on Django. Every time I refresh the page, the console throws me a ResourceNotFoundException - Requested resource not found, which seems to be happening when I use table.scan(). On certain pages the table still loads, but on others' I'm shown a debug error.

Here's a part of my code:

```
dynamodb = boto3.resource(
    'dynamodb',
    aws_access_key_id="XXXXXX",
    aws_secret_access_key="XXXXXX",
    region_name="eu-west-2"
)    
table = dynamodb.Table(table_name)
response = table.scan(TableName=table_name)
```

I'm entirely sure that the table_name value contains the correct string.

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are confusing the [Client-level scan](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/dynamodb.html#DynamoDB.Client.scan) method with the [Resource-level scan](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/dynamodb.html#DynamoDB.Table.scan) method. The former requires you to provide a `TableName` parameter, while the latter does not (because it's a method on an existing `Table` object, so the table name is implicitly known).

Also, see [Difference in boto3 between resource, client, and session?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42809096/difference-in-boto3-between-resource-client-and-session)