# Switch AWS Accounts in Python - EC2 Object has no attribute 'instances' error

Tags: python, boto

I'm trying to list the EC2 instances in a specific AWS account using named profiles and boto3 in Python.

The error says:

```
File ".\aws_ec2_list_instance_info.py", line 18, in <module>
    running_instances = ec2.instances.filter(Filters=[{
  File "C:\Users\tdunphy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\botocore\client.py", line 601, in __getattr__
    self.__class__.__name__, item)
AttributeError: 'EC2' object has no attribute 'instances'
```

This is my code:

```
from collections import defaultdict
import boto3
aws_account = input("Enter the name of the AWS account you'll be working in: ")
# Connect to EC2
session = boto3.Session(profile_name=aws_account)
ec2 = session.client('ec2')
# Get information for all running instances
running_instances = ec2.instances.filter(Filters=[{
    'Name': 'instance-state-name',
    'Values': ['running']}])
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to include which version of Boto 3 you are using. The current Boto 3 (ver. 1.9.108) documentation does not list `instances` as a method of `EC2.Client`.

Comment: Ok. How do I determine the version of boto3 that I'm using?

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't seem to be an instance function for ec2 client.  Maybe something like this is what you're looking for?

describe_instances, https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Client.describe_instances

Comment: Ok, I can probably alter the code to use describe_instannces. But I notice if I switch to boto3.resource the code I have works, without switching accounts:`ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2') running_instances = ec2.instances.filter(Filters=[{
    'Name': 'instance-state-name',
    'Values': ['running']}])` returns `------
Name: USAWSCDLX00061
Instance ID: i-0463897140af217f8
Type: m4.large
State: running
Private IP: 10.48.136.41
Public IP: None
Launch Time: 2017-12-20 14:26:30+00:00`

Comment: I have two questions. What's the difference between boto3.resource and boto3.client? Is there any way to do account switching using boto3.resource?

Comment: I'm going to point to you this post that explains it pretty well, https://stackoverflow.com/a/48867829/11149832

Comment: OK perfect! Thanks I will check this out.

Comment: Update. This works when I switch it to a boto3 resource instead of a client. And I am able to switch accounts: `session = boto3.Session(profile_name=aws_account)
ec2 = session.resource('ec2')`

Answer (score -1):

check out the boto3 documentation here. https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Client.describe_instances
or check out this https://github.com/CloudBoltSoftware/cloudbolt-forge/blob/master/blueprints/aws_rds_instance/create_aws_rds_instance.py