# Different ways of reading data from s3 bucket using boto3

Tags: json, python-3.x, amazon-s3, python-requests, boto3

I'm trying to read some json file from s3 bucket and then trying to post the data into rds and redshift(using a post api developed/intended for that).

I approached to do this in 2 ways using boto3. Below are those:

**1st way:**

```
import boto3
import json
import requests

url = 'xxxx.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com/v1'
headers = {'content-type': 'application/json', 'Host': 'development.my.dns.com'}
endpoint = url+'/my/post/endpoint'
s3_client = boto3.client("s3")
fileObj = s3_client.get_object(Bucket='my-bucket-name', Key='my-key-name'])
data = fileObj['Body'].read().decode('utf-8')
with requests.request('POST', endpoint, data=data, headers=headers, auth=(username, pwd), verify=False, stream=True) as r:
    print("Status Code:",r.status_code)
```

**2nd way:**

```
import boto3
import json
import requests

url = 'xxxx.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com/v1'
headers = {'content-type': 'application/json', 'Host': 'development.my.dns.com'}
endpoint = url+'/my/post/endpoint'
s3_res = boto3.resource('s3')
contentObj = s3_res.Object('my-bucket-name', 'my-key-name')
fileContent = contentObj.get()['Body'].read().decode('utf-8')
data = json.dumps(json.loads(fileContent))
with requests.request('POST', endpoint, data=data, headers=headers, auth=(username, pwd), verify=False, stream=True) as r:
    print("Status Code:",r.status_code)
```

Basically everything is same(`url`, `endpoint`, `headers`, `requests.request`) and `type(data)` is `<class 'str'>` in both the approaches. But the status codes are always different.

The 2nd way gives `Status Code: 200`. But the 1st way gives `Status Code: 413` or `Status Code: 502` randomly

Can any one please explain why is it this way? what's different in the above two approaches? I'm trying to understand what's going on when boto3 `read()` the data differently.

Comment: Could you please confirm if the `data` variable contains exactly the same thing in both cases, including all field values and data types.

Comment: Potentially relevant answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42809096/difference-in-boto3-between-resource-client-and-session

Comment: Yes the `data` content in both the cases is same. Except in 1st way, the data is indented and in the 2nd way it is not.