# How to get the value of aws iam list-account-aliases as variable?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I want to write a python program to check which account I am in by using account alias (I have multiple Tennants et up on AWS). I think `aws iam list-account-aliases` return what exactly I am looking for but it is a command line results and I am not sure what is the best to capture as variable in a python program.

Also I was reading about the `aws iam list-account-aliases` and they have a output section mentioned `AccountAliases -> (list)`. (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/iam/list-account-aliases.html)

I wonder what this `AccountAliases` is? an option? a command? a variable? I was a little bit confused here.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Boto3` to get the account alias in `python`. Your link points to `aws-cli`.

Here is the link for equivalent `Boto3` command for `python`:
https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/iam.html#IAM.Client.list_account_aliases

Sample code:

```py
import boto3

client = boto3.client('iam')

response = client.list_account_aliases()
```

Response:

```
{
    'AccountAliases': [
        'myawesomeaccount',
    ],
    'IsTruncated': True,
}
```

Comment: Thank you and it works! I guess I need to take a look of boto3 :)

Answer (score 1):

Account alias on AWS is a readable alias created against AWS user's account id. You can find more info here : 
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/console_account-alias.html

AWS has provided a very well documented library for Python called `Boto3` which can be used to obtain connect to your AWS account as client, resource or session (more information on these in SO answer here: [Difference in boto3 between resource, client, and session?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42809096/difference-in-boto3-between-resource-client-and-session))

For your use case you can connect to your AWS as client with `iam` label:

```
import boto3

client = boto3.client(
            'iam', 
            region_name="region_name",
            aws_access_key_id="your_aws_access_key_id",
            aws_secret_access_key="your_aws_secret_access_key")

account_aliases = client. list_account_aliases()
```

The response is a JSON object which can be traversed to get the desired information on aliases.