# S3 object has no attribute Bucket

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto, attributeerror

I am trying to run a code snippet like this:

```
s3_file_path = "testunzipping/sample.csv.gz"
s3 = boto3.client('s3')
lst = s3.list_objects(Bucket='testunzipping')['Contents']
firstbucket = s3.Bucket('testunzipping')
```

but I am getting an error on the last line that:

```
"errorMessage": "'S3' object has no attribute 'Bucket'",
```

Later I am using the first bucket like this:

```
firstbucket.upload_fileobj(destination_file_gz, s3_filename)
```

What am I doing wrong? I also tried with `bucket` instead of `Bucket`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference in boto3 between resource, client, and session?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42809096/difference-in-boto3-between-resource-client-and-session)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a difference between [`boto.client`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#client) and [`boto.resource`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#bucket)

`.Bucket` is only defined on the latter:

```
s3_resource = boto3.resource('s3')
bucket = s3.Bucket('name')
```

vs.

```
s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
s3.list_objects(...)
```

Comment: What about the open function? ```(s3.open(s3_file_path, mode="wb"))``` It gives me an error with both S3 (client) and s3_resource (resource)

Comment: @x89 there is no such thing as `s3.open` in boto. Are you sure you want to `open` an s3 object and not a local file?