# How do I Update a Row in Dynamo-db using AWS Python Lambda?

Tags: python, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

Here is what I got so far:

```
def update_status(migrationId, status):
    table = dynamodb.Table('rockar-dev-data-migration-state')
    response = table.update_item(
    Key={'migrationId': migrationId},
    AttributeUpdates={
        'state': status,
        'timeStamp': dt.now()
    }
)
```

This fails with an error: 'DynamoDB' object has no attribute 'Table'

I have also tried this:

```
def update_status(migrationId, status):
    
    response = dynamodb.update_item(
       TableName='rockar-dev-data-migration-state',
        Key={ 'migrationId': migrationId },
        UpdateExpression="set state =:st",
        ExpressionAttributeValues={
            ':st': status

        },
        ReturnValues="UPDATED_NEW"
    )
    return response
```

but this produces an error too:
Invalid type for parameter Key.migrationId, value: 1234567, type: <class 'str'>, valid types: <class 'dict'>

How do i go about this?

Many thanks

Comment: Please add the code that creates the `dynamodb` variable - you're probably confusing the client and resource APIs in boto3.

Comment: Related: [Difference in boto3 between resource, client, and session?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42809096/difference-in-boto3-between-resource-client-and-session)