# How to use aioboto3 & asyncio to download file from S3 aws - Python

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-s3, boto3, python-asyncio, aio

I have the sync script which is running & working well, but i see some download files takes time, thought of using async approach here.

```
import json
import os
import io
import time
import gzip
import re
import logging
from logging.handlers import RotatingFileHandler
import boto3

AWS_KEY = "**"
AWS_SECRET = "**"
QUEUE_URL = "***"
OUTPUT_PATH = "./test"
VISIBILITY_TIMEOUT = 10
REGION_NAME = "region"

sqs = boto3.resource('sqs', region_name=REGION_NAME, aws_access_key_id=AWS_KEY, aws_secret_access_key=AWS_SECRET)
s3 = boto3.client('s3', region_name=REGION_NAME, aws_access_key_id=AWS_KEY, aws_secret_access_key=AWS_SECRET)

queue = sqs.Queue(url=QUEUE_URL)

def handle_response(msg, path):
    """Logic goes here"""
    print('message: %s' % msg)

def download_message_files(msg):
    for s3_file in msg['files']:
        s3_path = s3_file['path']
        with io.BytesIO() as f:
            s3.download_fileobj(msg['bucket'], s3_path, f)
            f.seek(0)
            for line in gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=f):
                await handle_response(line.decode('UTF-8'), s3_path)

def consume():
    while True:
        for msg in queue.receive_messages(VisibilityTimeout=VISIBILITY_TIMEOUT):
            body = json.loads(msg.body)  # grab the actual message body
            download_message_files(body)
            msg.delete()
            time.sleep(sleep_time)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Setup our root logger
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO, format="%(asctime)s %(name)s %(levelname)s %(message)s")
    # Create our FDR logger
    logger = logging.getLogger("Consumer")
    # Rotate log file handler
    RFH = RotatingFileHandler("test.log", maxBytes=20971520, backupCount=5)
    # Log file output format
    F_FORMAT = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s %(name)s %(levelname)s %(message)s')
    # Set the log file output level to INFO
    RFH.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    # Add our log file formatter to the log file handler
    RFH.setFormatter(F_FORMAT)
    # Add our log file handler to our logger
    logger.addHandler(RFH)
    consume()
```

I have tried converting this using aioboto3 and got struck in queue approach.

```
    session = aioboto3.Session()
    sqs = session.resource('sqs', region_name=REGION_NAME, aws_access_key_id=AWS_KEY, aws_secret_access_key=AWS_SECRET)
    s3 = session.client('s3', region_name=REGION_NAME, aws_access_key_id=AWS_KEY, aws_secret_access_key=AWS_SECRET)
queue = sqs.Queue(url=QUEUE_URL)  <---- this gives error as 'ResourceCreatorContext' object has no attribute 'Queue'
```

As i could understand from this there is no attribute, but could anyone guide me to make this working with async nature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `asyncio` and `aioboto3` together.

Instead of creating a `resource`, you can use `client`. The difference between an `aioboto3.client` and `aioboto3.resource` can be found in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48867829/8434467).

This is a simple working example:

```
import aioboto3

async def consume():
  async with aioboto3.Session().client(service_name='sqs', region_name=REGION_NAME, aws_access_key_id=AWS_KEY, aws_secret_access_key=AWS_SECRET) as client:
    messages = await (client.receive_messages(VisibilityTimeout=VISIBILITY_TIMEOUT)
    for message in messages:
      # Do something
```

This should solve the error you are facing. This solution can also be [extended](https://aioboto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html) to S3 as per your requirements.