# AttributeError: 'EC2' object has no attribute 'instances'. Did you mean: 'run_instances'?

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3

I want to create a client from a session object as I have different profiles and would like to keep each session different per profile. Something similar as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42809096/difference-in-boto3-between-resource-client-and-session)

```
aws_session_obj = boto3.session.Session(
    profile_name="system-profile", region_name="us-east-2"
)
    ec2 = aws_session_obj.client("ec2")
    for instance in ec2.instances.all():
    …
```

However, above results in below error. Not sure, what am i doing wrong here.

```
botocore/client.py", line 888, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(
AttributeError: 'EC2' object has no attribute 'instances'. Did you mean: 'run_instances'?
```

Comment: Have you tried using `aws_session_obj.resource("ec2")` instead of `aws_session_obj.client("ec2")`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The EC2 client does not have an `instances` attribute ([docs](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html)).

You should use the [ServiceResource](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2/service-resource/instances.html) instead.

```py
obj = boto3.session.Session(
    profile_name="system-profile",
    region_name="us-east-2"
)

ec2 = aws_session_obj.resource("ec2")
for instance in ec2.instances.all():
    ...
```